# How to get Edittext(Multiline) leftdrawable on top position

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I am using `Edittext` with `textMultiLine` attributes. I got edittext text on top position using `android:gravity="top"`. But I cannot get `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_message"` on top position.

[image]

I want `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_message"` on top position(left of the *Message* text)

**Edits**

My `Edittext` xml is as below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtContactMessage"
    style="@style/styleRoundedEdittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tendp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_message"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/strMessage"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:maxLength="500"
    android:minHeight="120dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

Comment: You may use relative or frame layout for this.

Comment: Show me your EditText, and I will try to convert it to what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to set the left drawable on a EditText at the top position like that, you would need to wrap your EditText inside a parent layout where you can place a ImageView that draws the icon at this position instead.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:contentDescription="message icon"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Message"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this :

```
 <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        **<!-- Edit text with drawable at top left -->**
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:hint="Enter text"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
        </FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per **TouchBoarder**'s answer I got Edittext(Multiline) leftdrawable on top position :)

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="message icon"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/tendp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_message" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Message" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]