# How can I change the position of drawable in TextInputEditText?

Tags: android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I set a drawable in a TextInputEditText with attribute android:drawableStart, and it looks like this:

[drawable default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MpR9.png)

But actually, I need to put it in this way:

[The drawable in the way I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy6ai.png)

It seems to there's no attribute in xml to do this, I review the properties and nothing seems to fit what I want.
Also, I've been looking for a while on Internet but I don´t get the information that I need to achieve this.  **Any idea???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After keep searching on Internet, I was able to find a solution. First of all at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805452/how-to-get-edittextmultiline-leftdrawable-on-top-position), it suggests in the accepted answer, that it is not possible to place the icon at the top, however, you have to wrap the EditText inside a LinearLayout and he place the
example code below:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:contentDescription="message icon"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Message"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I took that idea, and achieved it by overlapping the icon inside the TextInputLayout with a FrameLayout wrapped in a LinearLayout. My code looks like this:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@drawable/edt_bg_selector_fafa_orange"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilComentReporte"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                app:errorTextColor="@color/colorRojo"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_bg_selector_fafa_orange"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etComentReporte"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:gravity="top|start"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoComplete"
                    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_describe_tu_problema"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_contacto_nar" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like this on device:

[The view now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUtX5.png)